# How to get count with joins in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, count

I am joining 3 tables and fetching data from database. But my problem is that I have to use 2 more tables to query to fetch a number of likes and numbers of comments on a post.

The query I am using is:

```
function GetHomeDeals($limit,$start)
{
    $this->db->from('tbl_coupons');
    $this->db->where('coupon_status', 'active');
    $this->db->join('tbl_stores','tbl_stores.store_id=tbl_coupons.coupon_store');
    $this->db->join('tbl_users','tbl_users.user_id=tbl_coupons.coupon_postedby');
    $this->db->limit( $start,$limit);
    $this->db->order_by("coupon_id", "desc"); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    //echo $this->db->last_query();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

table structure of likes tables is:

```
like_id
like_by
like_on
```

table structure for comments

```
comment_id
comment_by
comment_on
comment
```

How can i add a count of likes and comments my function?

I just want total number of likes and count in result

```
like_on= coupon_id
comment_on=coupon_id
```

[image: click to view desired output]

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$query->num_rows();
```

example:

```
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$num = $query->num_rows();
```